# Regular Expressions Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, palindrome

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var cleanStr = str.replace(/_\W/g, "");
  return cleanStr;
}

palindrome("_eye");
```

The above mentioned code returns "_eye" as the output. I might be missing something very obvious but why isn't the regular expression working? The intent is to remove any characters that are not words or numbers.

Comment: Your regular expression is for "underscore followed by non-word-character/non-digit". You will need to use the OR operator `|` to match either of these.

Comment: @Bergi this worked as well! Also appreciate the explanation, makes usage a lot more clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use brackets around the characters. Also, put a `+` after the brackets to remove continuous occurence of such characters.

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var cleanStr = str.replace(/[_\W]+/g, "");
  return cleanStr;
}
console.log(palindrome("_eye"));
```

Comment: Will still work without `+` since you're using global flag. I would like to know which is faster though, not that it matters here anyway.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande -- Hope [this](https://jsperf.com/regex-test-with-plus/1) helps.

Comment: @31piy Thanks! I also want to clarify, since the solution in the comment above also works equally well in my case, where to use which?

Comment: @alhamz -- Use as you please. Both are viable and valid solutions.